# Regular Expression Except this Characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am using MVC data annotations and my requirement is that the address field can contain any characters (i.e. other than English characters are also allowed) except `< > . ! @ # % / ? *`.

I searched many sites but not getting how to write this regex.

So far I have tried:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[<>.!@#%/]+$", ErrorMessage = "Address invalid.")]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, you are only allowing string consisting ONLY of these letters.

Use

```
"^[^<>.!@#%/]+$"
```

Comment: I think, you are missing `?` and `*` from the `OP`s requirement that says: Contains any characters except :`< > . ! @ # % / ? *`. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 17):

Make your regex choose from any characters **except** the ones listed with the caret:

```
[^abc]
```

will match anything that's not an a, b, or c.

So putting it all together, your regex would be

```
^[^<>!@#%/?*]+$
```

Note here that the caret outside the square braces means 'match the start of the line', yet inside the square brackets means 'match anything that **is not** any of the following'

Comment: You don't need to escape regex metacharacters in a character class (except backslash and closing bracket).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Why the accepter response is missing the characters `?` and `*` in the pattern. Am I misunderstanding something here? Please help.

Comment: Yes, I think they are missing.

Comment: @agetgonzo Thanks for a response with a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try is regular expression:

```
[^<>.!@#%/?*]
```

Comment: You can remove all those backslashes. Also, this only matches one character.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

> "[^<>.!@#%/]"

**EDIT**:

. (dot) is a reserved character in Regular Expressions, so you need to escape it.